# Creating wss socket with ws npm library - error: socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, websocket

Is there a way in which I can create and connect to a websocket server that has accepts `wss` rather than just `ws` in the path?

I am currently using the `ws` npm library to do something like:

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 8080});

wss.on('connection', () => {
    console.log('connected!');
});
```

Then connecting in terminal:

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8080
```

I would connect successfully and get the correct log message.

However I am wanting/needing to connect to a `wss` websocket, but cannot get this to work with the `ws` npm library.

```
wscat -c wss://localhost:8080
```

This returns the error: `error: socket hang up`

Is there some way around this at all?

Answer (score -1):

You need to open a HTTPS server, in order to connect to it.
This is also explained in the documentation of ws.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = https.createServer({
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem')
});
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

[WS with HTTPS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#external-https-server)

You can create certificates with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/de/)